# Cross Class Subclass use

Tags: python, class

I am experimenting with python object orientated programming. Of course I learned about inheritence and so on, but this question is very specific and I couldn't find the answer anywhere yet.

Let's say we have a class `class mainClass:`. In this class there is a function `def func(self):`. And within this function `func()` I want to use two custom classes. Can I and how can I use the first custom class within the second one? (Here's a example)

```
class custom1:
    def func1(self):
        #do something

class custom2:
    def func2(self):
        #call function func1 from class custom1 without creating another instance

class mainClass:
    def func(self):
        obj1 = custom1()
        obj2 = custom2()
        obj2.func2()
```

Like I said I don't want to create a second instance of `custom1` within `custom2`. Only the one in `mainClass`.

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: So pass it as an argument to the function?

Comment: `custom2` needs *some* way of accessing the instance you want it to call `func1` from

Comment: Python is lexically scoped. `obj2.func2` cannot access the scope it is *called from*, only the scope it is *defined in*. It also doesn't really make sense to take abut how to use the instance methods defined in a class without having a *specific* instance of the class in mind. `custom1.func` is not a function that anyone can or should call: it's a function intended to be used by specific instances of `custom1` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about passing it via the constructor of the first class?

```
class custom1:
    def func1(self):
        #do something

class custom2:
    def __init__(self, obj1):
        self._obj1 = obj1

    def func2(self):
        self._obj1.func1()


class mainClass:
    def func(self):
        obj1 = custom1()
        obj2 = custom2(obj1)
        obj2.func2()
```

Comment: For everyone having the same question/problem: That works perfectly fine.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser you can accept the answer & upvote it that case :)